# AWS: need guidance to deploy my Django Project

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a Django web app. I am planning to deploy on the AWS web server.

I am using celery and rabbitmq que manager for my application.

I have read about the AWS services.

I have two options use :

1) AWS Elastic Beanstalk or

2) Create an EC2 instance of linux and install postgresql, celery, rabbitmq etc

So which is better to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS EC2 is always a better option as it gives you complete access on the OS and physical access to the data storage. This will help you to manage your application is a much more efficient way. Also EC2 instance can not only host a single application but can have as much ever applications that you require(depends on the capacity/instance type of the server). This will let you tweak the webserver proxy as well.

In case of Beanstalk you do not get similar options, you have to manage the applications with the options that are available to you.

To summarise: 
In case you want complete control of you application - Use EC2.
If you are looking for a managed service wherein not much control is required you can opt for Beanstalk. Personally I would like to have the entire control over my application ;)

Comment: Also should i use separate EBS (storage block) where i will put all my application related code files and data and attach to the ECS instance (even though the ECS itself has an EBS (storage block) on which the OS is insalled and booted).  OR just use the EC2 instance with its EBS and keep taking snapshots if we want to restore

Comment: It is better to use a separate EBS volume for deploying your application. This will help you manage the data better and the same will be available in case of any OS level failures. I suggest to use a separate disk mounted at /opt and use the same for your application